# When using self over static

Tags: php

As of version 5.3, PHP have implemented the [**Late Static Bindings**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), *which can be used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance*.

In general, the `static::` seems to be more useful than `self::` in a lot of contexts, mainly if you like to able that your classes and methods be extended. Seems do not make sense you call a method from your class like `self::someMethod()`, because it can cause a not reliable behaviour if you extended this class and override this method.

**For instance ([*live example*](https://3v4l.org/6AmPG)):**

```
class ParentClass {
    public static function someMethod ()       { return 'ParentClass::someMethod()'; }
    public static function getSomeMethodData() { return self::someMethod(); }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public static function someMethod ()       { return 'ChildClass::someMethod()'; }
}

ChildClass::getSomeMethodData();
// Return -> "ParentClass::getSomeMethodData()"
// Not    -> "ChildClass ::getSomeMethodData()"
```

You can change this behaviour if you replace the `self::` with the `static::`.

**Okay, after the *blábláblá*, my question is:** there are some context where we SHOULD use the `self::` instead of `static::` for methods or properties?

I mean, can I replace all `self::` with `static::` without it change my code behaviour for all my codebase?

**Edit #1:** to make it more clear. Which case I MUST use `self::` instead of `static::`? I mean, in which context is **inevitable** the use of `self::`? For instance, I can consider `self::class`, but it can be replaced by `__CLASS__` (despite I still prefer the `self::class` version).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not my doubt. **The question is:** which case I MUST use `self::` instead of `static::`. I mean, in which context is inevitable the use of `self::`? For instance, I can consider `self::class`, but it can be replaced by `__CLASS__` (despite I prefer the `self::class` version).

Comment: It is not a valid response. For instance, can I replace `intval()` to `(int)` to all my codebase? The answer is justly "**yes**". Because it will never affect the behaviour, in any case. My doubt here is not about a specific codebase. I am working on an inspection for the [PHP Inspections EA](https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/issues/428) plugin, and I like to suggests that user replace `self::` to `static::` to any case (except when `final` modifier is applicated) to make possible the expansibility of class (respecting the OCP - _open/closed principle_).

Comment: It is true if you have a code like `intval($n)`, same is valid for `strval()` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between self and static. If you call the method with static, it will be run in the context of the class where the method actually is.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the question is not that. Read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396661/when-using-self-over-static#comment77754936_45396661).